# After disown a process how can I again read the stdout of the running process

Tags: linux, command-line, process, terminal, background-process

I have a c program which is running on linux. I applied some command for running the process in background after closing the terminal.

```
1. Pause program with `Ctrl-Z`, 
2. Pull it into the background with `bg` 
3. Then disown it.
```

Now i want to see the console output of this program which is still running.

How can I do it in linux?

Comment: If the terminal used to run the command has been closed and you are using a new one, I guess that the standard output of the background process was closed, so that you cannot do that. A very simple way is to use `screen`, another way is to redirect output to a file when the command is run, and access the file later.

Answer (score 1):

If the terminal used to run the command has been closed and you are using a new one, I guess that the standard output of the background process was closed, so that you cannot do that.

A very simple way is to use `screen`.

Another way is to redirect output to a file when the command is run, and access the file later.